# Creating CSS circles connected with lines vertical and horizontal

Tags: css

I want to create a circle with lines on the right and bottom in CSS. Similar on the picture below. I found a css [code](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/cEntL) that connect circles horizontally. I cannot figure out how will add the line vertically or similar to the image I attached?

[image]

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <style>
            @import "compass/css3";

            li {
                width: 2em;
                height: 2em;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 2em;
                border-radius: 1em;
                background: dodgerblue;
                margin: 0 1em;
                display: inline-block;
                color: white;
                position: relative;
            }

            li::before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                top: .9em;
                left: -4em;
                width: 4em;
                height: .2em;
                background: dodgerblue;
                z-index: -1;
            }

            li:first-child::before {
                display: none;
            }

            .active {
                background: dodgerblue;
            }

            .active ~ li {
                background: lightblue;
            }

            .active ~ li::before {
                background: lightblue;
            }

            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                padding: 2em;
            }
        </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <ul>
             <li>1</li>
             <li>2</li>
             <li>3</li>
             <li class="active">4</li>
             <li>5</li>
             <li>6</li>
             <li>7</li>
         </ul>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out updated pen :

http://codepen.io/Debabrata89/pen/QNZrxE

Below are the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div></div><span id="step1">step1</span>
<div id="second"></div>
<div></div><span id="step2">step2</span>
<div id="last"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

div {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
 -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg); 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); 
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

div::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  z-index: -1;

}



div:first-child::after {
  display: none;
}



body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2em;
}
#last{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
 #second{
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   width:0;
   height:10;
   left:16px;
   top:-16px;

}
#step1{
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:150px
}
#step2{
  position:absolute;
  top:104px;
  left:150px
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a combination of pseudo-elements to achieve the goal.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  font: normal 16px/22px Arial;
  color: #999;
}
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 10px 35px;
  }
  li::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 9px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 999px;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
    border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
    }
    li:last-child::before {
      border-width: 2px 0 0;
      }
  li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }
  li.current,
  li.passed {
    color: #000;
    }
    li.current::before {
      border-top-color: dodgerblue;
      }
    li.current::after {
      border-color: dodgerblue;
      background: dodgerblue;
      }
    li.passed::before,
    li.passed::after {
      border-color: dodgerblue;
      }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="passed">Step #1</li>
  <li class="passed">Step #2</li>
  <li class="passed">Step #3</li>
  <li class="current">Step #4<br><small><i>Description of the step</i></small></li>
  <li>Step #5</li>
  <li>Step #6</li>
  <li>Step #7</li>
</ul>
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5Lm0zgd/) if you prefer

Comment: can you animate the line slowly from top to bottom..?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohctqyq7/) .

I changed some properties and added li:after.

```
li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 1em 1em;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.1em;
  left: 1em;
  /* width: 4em; */
  width: .2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  z-index: -1;
}
li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  z-index: -1;
}
li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.active ~ li {
  background: lightblue;
}
.active ~ li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2em;
}
```